# Lambda: node.js not waiting until promise return

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, promise, aws-lambda

I wrote a lambda function but unfortunately, I am not sure why it is not waiting for promise result. would you mind help me to figure it out what is the problem?

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  let request = new Request(event);
  console.log(`request---> ${JSON.stringify(request)}`);
  try {
    let props = { ...request.payload };
    let poolData = Helper.getPoolData();
    console.log(`props---> ${JSON.stringify(props)} \npoolData---> ${JSON.stringify(poolData)}`);
    let profileData = profile(poolData, props);
    console.log(`before await...`);
    let data = await profileData;
    console.log(`after await...`);
    return request.reply(data);
  } catch (err) {  
    console.log(`ERROR HAPPENED ------profile_get.js-----> ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
    return request.reply(Boomer(err));
  }
};
```

my profile function is as below:

```
static async profile(poolData, props) {
    console.log(`inside profile--->`);
    const cognitoUser = await Helper.getCognitoUser(poolData, props);
    console.log(`cognitoUser---> ${JSON.stringify(cognitoUser)}`);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let next = (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(res);
        }
      };
      console.log(`inside promise`);

      cognitoUser.getUserAttributes(next);
    });
  }
```

My log details in Cloudwatch is as below:

```
2019-12-25T02:10:46.149+08:00
START RequestId: 9f6a0e99-543c-4e1c-b41d-af9dba32739d Version: $LATEST
2019-12-25T02:10:46.178+08:00
2019-12-24T18:10:46.152Z 9f6a0e99-543c-4e1c-b41d-af9dba32739d INFO request---> {"headers":{"Accept":"*/*","AcceptEn....l}
2019-12-25T02:10:46.178+08:00
2019-12-24T18:10:46.178Z 9f6a0e99-543c-4e1c-b41d-af9dba32739d INFO props---> {"Accept":"*/*","AcceptEncod...,"XForwardedProto":"https"} poolData---> {"UserPoolId":"eu-west-asdasda","ClientId":"asdasd","Paranoia":"7"}
2019-12-25T02:10:46.178+08:00
2019-12-24T18:10:46.178Z 9f6a0e99-543c-4e1c-b41d-af9dba32739d INFO inside profile--->
2019-12-25T02:10:46.198+08:00
2019-12-24T18:10:46.179Z 9f6a0e99-543c-4e1c-b41d-af9dba32739d INFO before await...
2019-12-25T02:10:46.198+08:00
2019-12-24T18:10:46.198Z 9f6a0e99-543c-4e1c-b41d-af9dba32739d INFO ERROR HAPPENED ------profile_get.js-----> {}
2019-12-25T02:10:46.198+08:00
2019-12-24T18:10:46.198Z 9f6a0e99-543c-4e1c-b41d-af9dba32739d INFO ERROR HAPPENED ------error.js-----> {}
2019-12-25T02:10:46.219+08:00
END RequestId: 9f6a0e99-543c-4e1c-b41d-af9dba32739d
2019-12-25T02:10:46.219+08:00
REPORT RequestId: 9f6a0e99-543c-4e1c-b41d-af9dba32739d Duration: 69.30 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB M
```

I am using Node.js 12.x.

Comment: `Helper.getCognitoUser(poolData, props);` produces an error. Instead of logging `JSON.stringify(err)` in your `catch` handler, log `err` in a separate `console.log(err)` so you can see all the error properties in the console and get informed of what went wrong.

Comment: can you remove the json stringify from your catch and just log `err` and see what is the issue? basically
    `console.log(err);`

Comment: @trincot: your assumption was correct. but what is the difference between stringify the err and without it?

Comment: error can not be stringified the way you are doing. try this `JSON.stringify(err, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err))`

Comment: @AshishModi: tq noted. I found the issue. it was due to name of the refresh token,.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` only serialises [*enumerable*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) properties. Those of an Error object are (often) not enumerable.